# html_nodes extraction of 1 number takes so long

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Hi can someone please help me here?
The extraction of just 1 number from the website takes more than 5 secs. Is there a faster way of extracting this P/E ratio from the website?

```
library(rvest)
library(zoo)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

my.url <- 'https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239726/ishares-core-sp-500-etf'
my.xpath <- '//*[@id="fundamentalsAndRisk"]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]'
my.node <- html_nodes(read_html(my.url), xpath = my.xpath) %>% 
    html_text()
pe1 <- as.numeric(str_extract_all(my.node, "[0-9].+")[[1]])
```

Comment: The site load and node find take abt ~2s for me. You should put the `read_html()` in a separate operation both to be a courteous scraper and to isolate performance issues since I'm 99.999% certain the site is taking a long-ish time to load for you. If you can install the `pingr` package, what do `median(pingr::ping("www.ishares.com"))` and `median(pingr::ping_port("www.ishares.com", 443))` report and what does `httr::GET(my.url)$times['total']` report?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I guess it is due to my country,s slower network